# Why can you measure input and output impedance of a amplifier circuit with a resistance/potentiometer?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, resistance, impedance, active-components

While running simulations for a circuit I measured the input and output impedance by simply adding a potentiometer, turn it up until the voltage peak to peak signal going out reached half and then supposedly the resistance then is the same as the input impedance. Why is it that you can do this? It becomes a voltage divider circuit or what?

The circuit [image]

[image]

Comment: Yes matched impedance will achieve 50%Vac unless there is current limiting or clipping. since the Ce amp is a current source, it is  defined by Rc with some Early effect leakage and output capacitance, which you normally neglect unless Rc~1M or so. zin is simply Zc1+R1//R2// {Reb/Zce(f)/hFE+rBE}

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, that will not give the correct answer unless the input impedance has no imaginary component. It may be "close enough" in your circuit if the value of C is sufficiently high and the frequency is not too high or too low.

If it's resistive then it's just a voltage divider.